# Как подключить SFTP на мой сайт? Подключить плагин BorwserSync для удаленного сайта?

Tags: gulp, ftp, синхронизация, hosting, sftp

Всем привет! Как сделать так, чтобы при редактировании кода в Sublime Text 3 при сохранении изменений, локальные файлы на компьютере автоматически попадали на мой сайт? Также, мне нужно, подключить BrowserSync к моей Gulp сборке, чтобы он обновлял не локальные файлы на диске, а уже файлы, загруженные на мой сайт?

Comment: Собрались редактировать сайт прямо на продакшене? Это вредно для здоровья

Comment: @andreymal по делу есть что сказать?